# Is there a way to unit test localization resources in asp.net core class libarary?

Tags: unit-testing, localization, asp.net-core, mstest, class-library

I want to have a resource class library and test it in another mstest class libary. 
this is my project.json in resource library : (my resx file is in Resources folder)

```
{
  "version": "1.0.0-*",
  "dependencies": {
  "NETStandard.Library": "1.6.0",
  "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.DataAnnotations": "1.0.1"
 },
 "buildOptions": {
  "embed": {
    "include": [ "Resources/PS.ModelBase.Models.Person.fa.resx" ]
  }
 },
 "frameworks": {
  "netstandard1.6": {
   "imports": "dnxcore50"
  }
}
  }
```

and this is my test method :

```cs
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Resources;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace PS.ModelBaseTest
{
[TestClass]
public class PersonTest
{
    [TestMethod]
    public void FullNameValidateNullFirstName()
    {
        ResourceManager rm = new ResourceManager(typeof(PS.ModelBase.Models.Person));
        string test = rm.GetString("Fisrt Name", new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("fa-IR"));
        Assert.AreEqual("Fisrt Name", test);

    }
  }
 }
```

I have this error when I run the test :

> Could not find any resources appropriate for the specified culture or
>   the neutral culture.  Make sure "PS.ModelBase.Models.Person.resources"
>   was correctly embedded or linked into assembly "PS.ModelBase" at
>   compile time, or that all the satellite assemblies required are
>   loadable and fully signed.

what should I do ?

**َUpdate :**

Ok. I solved my problem by inserting resx to the Models folder (Where the Person class is in it ) and renamed resx files to class name (like Person.en.resx) .
Nothing to do with project.json :

```
{
   "dependencies": {
   "NETStandard.Library": "1.6.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.DataAnnotations": "1.0.1"
},
    "frameworks": {
    "netstandard1.6": {
     "imports": "dnxcore50"
 }
 },
 "version": "1.0.0-*"
}
```

But I faced another problem .I want to remain my resx files in Resources folder , not in Models folder! How can embed resx file to person class when is in Resources folder ?

**I got the second problem. In fact the resource file and the class must be in a same domain**

Comment: Try `"include": [ "Resources" ]` or `"includeFiles": [ "Resources/PS.ModelBase.Models.Person.fa.resx" ]`

Comment: I did the two of them but I got the same error again !!!

Comment: update question with the content of project.json

Comment: I did this ....

Comment: I think i got the second problem. In fact the resource file and the class must be in a same domain ...

Answer (score 1):

Using the following two resources as reference :

[Github Issue: Updates to project.json schema](https://github.com/aspnet/Announcements/issues/175#include-structure)

[project.json reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/core/tools/project-json)

Based on project file in question, either try

> - **"includeFiles" string/string[]**
>     A list of file paths to include. The paths are rooted at the project folder. This list has a higher
>     priority than the include and exclude globbing patterns, hence a file
>     listed here and in the exclude globbing pattern will still be
>     included. Defaults to none.

```
"buildOptions": {
  "embed": {
    "includeFiles": [ "Resources/PS.ModelBase.Models.Person.fa.resx" ]
  }
}
```

for just the one resource file, or

> - **"include" string/string[]**
>     A list of file globbing patterns for files
>     to include. The patterns are rooted at the project folder. Defaults to
>     none.

```
"buildOptions": {
  "embed": {
    "include": [ "Resources" ]
  }
}
```

for the contents of the `Resources` folder